# CSS: Line-height on inline headers disrupts line spacing

Tags: css, typography, typesetting

I have paragraphs with inline header spans that I'm trying to set to a grid.  To make sure that multi-line headers are properly spaced, I'm using line-height; however, this results in too much space between the first and second lines of the paragraph.  Also, multi-line headers seem not to be inlined.  *(Actual desired line-height of headers is 33px, but I made it 44px to accentuate the space between the first and second paragraph lines)*.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/NbTvu/4/ and https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhXK4.png

#### CSS:

```
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-top: 22px;
}

span.h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 22px;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<p>
     <span class=h1>DISCONTINUING PPIs</span>
    — Rebound acid-hypersecretion is an important consideration following abrupt cessation of prolonged treatment with PPIs. As a result, treatment should be tapered following prolonged or higher dose treatment with a PPI.
</p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your `font-size` is too big for the thing you want to achieve.

Look at this: if I remove the font-size and line-height, it works perfectly:

**http://jsfiddle.net/NbTvu/1/**

```
span.h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 22px;
}
```

Try to style from here.

And using `span class="h1"` is very very bad. Use a regular `h1` or give your span a better classname.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need that larger font size.  There are h2-5 elsewhere in the document as well.
I agree that naming the class h1 is awful, but I should have mentioned that I don't have access to the HTML.

Comment: I don't see any real issue using h1 as a class name? For example you might want to make h2's look like h1's but still keep the semantics of a h2 tag.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can play a little with margins:

```
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding:0;
}

span.h1 {
  font-size: 24px;

  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 21px;
}
```

and remove line-height... **http://jsfiddle.net/NbTvu/2/**

Comment: Messing with the margins throws off consecutive paragraphs.  Sorry, I should have mentioned these were snippets of a much larger document.  http://jsfiddle.net/NbTvu/3/
The issue is still being able to control the line height (the space between adjacent header lines) without disrupting the rest of the text.  Omitting the line-height simply makes it 22px.